# Godot. Animations tracks call scripts functions don't work

Tags: animation, godot

This is an animationPlayer created from a Blender import. Then I created a function call track and added a key to call a script function. This worked for idle and walk animation but not for attack animation.

My scene
[image]

My animatorPlayer, walk animtion. this work fine:
[image]

But this calls dont work:
[image]

my AnimationTree, only relevant nodes:
[image]

Thanks in advance.

I need it to function calls to functions anywhere. it is a critical functionality.

Comment: Is it giving you any error or warning when you run the animation?

Comment: No errors. i found a solution. now i put it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution thanks to:
https://godotengine.org/qa/52186/call-method-tracks-animation-work-another-animation-player

"In the animation tree on that blend node's bone filter there was a no name track/bone at the top that was filtered out, it is the call method track."

[image]

It's hard to see this.